# Extracting number values from attribute string with mixed data

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

In my attribute table, I have a column "Name" which contains data about type number and name of streets. For example: “SR 18 DI FIUGGI”. What I need is to create another column in which there will be only numeric data from column “Name”, so just "18".

I know how to do that in Excel, and that I can export/import data to do it there, but my guess is that you can do it directly in QGIS.

Also, one thing that can be useful to me is dividing columns by spaces. So there different columns for "SR", "18", "DI FIUGGI". Is this possible?

Comment: i suppose there can be streets 'names' containing numbers (which aren't "streets numbers") ?

Comment: How regular is this data? Are the 4th and 5th place always numbers? Or do the placs change?

Comment: Sometimes the numbers are three-digit, but they always go after the two-letter code.

Comment: Also they can be one-digit, ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

You are asking just the case that is given as an example of the `regexp_substr()` function:

```
regexp_substr("Name", '(\\d+)')
```

About your second question: You can create a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to group each first, second and "third" word (the "third" word will be all that follows the second space), and put each group in a matrix, with a `regexp_matches()` funtion.

Then, extract the value for each position in the matrix by its index with the `array_get()` function.

---

For the first word until a space:

```
array_get(regexp_matches("Name",'^(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)\\s([\\s\\S]+)'),0)
```

For the word between first and second spaces:

```
array_get(regexp_matches("Name",'^(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)\\s([\\s\\S]+)'),1)
```

And for all the characters that follows the second space:

```
array_get(regexp_matches("Name",'^(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)\\s([\\s\\S]+)'),2)
```